# Django Admin popup functionality

Tags: javascript, django, popup, admin

This topic is fairly common (most explicitly detailed here: http://www.hoboes.com/Mimsy/hacks/replicating-djangos-admin/), but I'm still having trouble with it.  I'm trying to use the "plus" button functionality used in the admin site where one can add an additional foreign key to a linked entry.  In the admin site, a popup displays allowing the user to submit a new field and then that new value is populated on the original form.

I think my issue centers around the inclusion of this line:

within the base.html template and the popadd.html template.  Clicking the plus button does not bring up a new window.  The popadd template simply loads in the same tab.  And submitting a new entry does not take the user back to the original form.

The admin site is functional.  I am including ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/admin/' in the settings.py file.  Does it have something to do with where the RelatedObjectLookups.js lives?  It's currently in an admin directory outside of my project folder.  Do I have to create a symlink?

Sorry for the noob questions.  Would appreciate any suggestions (as detailed as possible).

Comment: What browser are you using? What plugins (if any) do you have installed and how are they configured? In FF *Tab Mix Plus* (amongst others) is capable of radically changing how a popup/new window behaves.

Comment: I'm using firefox.  But I don't think it has to do with plugins/configuration.  The admin functionality works perfectly within the admin site. It's when I try to use it outside of this framework that I can't get it to work correctly.

Answer (score 13):

Following the steps outlined below will allow you to recreate Django admin's related object pop-up functionality without having to create any custom widgets, views, and urls. These steps assume you are trying to get this pop-up working in your own custom admin site which subclasses Django's admin.

Lets assume the following two models **Book** and **Author**, with an FK from Book to Author. Lets also assume that we'll want the ability to use the **Related Object Pop-Up** to add an Author when creating/editing a Book:

**[app_name]/models.py:**

```
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Lets create our custom admin site:

**[app_name]/sites.py:**

```
from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite

my_admin_site = AdminSite(name='my_custom_admin')
```

Our custom admin site will register two ModelAdmins to allow users to add/edit/delete both the Book and Author models:

**[app_name]/admin.py:**

```
from django.contrib.admin.options import ModelAdmin

from [app_name].forms import BookForm # We'll create this form below
from [app_name].models import Author, Book
from [app_name].sites import my_admin_site

class BookModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    form = BookForm()

# Register both models to our custom admin site
my_admin_site.register(Author, ModelAdmin)
my_admin_site.register(Book, BookModelAdmin)
```

Now, we'll setup the `BookForm` which is used in the `BookModelAdmin` above. This is where the magic happens. For more info on the RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper api, [click here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L228):

**[app_name]/forms.py:**

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper
from django import forms

from [app_name].models import Book
from [app_name].sites import my_admin_site

class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    author = Book._meta.get_field('author').formfield(
        widget=RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper(
            Book._meta.get_field('author').formfield().widget,
            Book._meta.get_field('author').rel,
            my_admin_site,
            can_add_related=True
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Book
```

**Notes:**

1. You will need to ensure that these two javascript files included in your templates: `admin/js/core.js` and `admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js`.

**Gotchas:**

1. `is_popup` needs to be set and passed correctly in your templates. Specifically, in any custom `change_form.html` templates you override, you must remember to add this line somewhere within your form tags: `{% if is_popup %}<input type="hidden" name="_popup" value="1" />{% endif %}`, so that the logic in [`BaseModelAdmin.response_add()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L812-817) returns the correct response.

**Under The Hood:** 
Essentially, we're re-using the form processing logic, widget wrapper and javascript that is already included with Django admin.

1. Using `RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper` to wrap the widget associated to the related object field in our form (and specifically passing `can_add_related=True` in the constructor) tells the widget to append the necessary '+' link with the appropriate javascript onclick event attached to it.
2. Django admin's javascript handles all of the logic necessary to launch the pop-up.
3. The `{% if is_popup %}...{% endif %}` logic in our `change_form.html` template(s) and the logic in `BaseModelAdmin.response_add()` handles the saving of the new related object and returns the appropriate javascript response that informs the pop-up that it needs to be closed.

**Related Repo:**
This public repo should provide sample code for the Django project discussed above: https://github.com/cooncesean/Books

Comment: Tks, exactly what I needed! BTW, you can now overwrite the widget inside the Meta class rather than rewriting the whole field -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

Comment: FYI,Field.rel has been deprecated since version 1.9 and replaced by Field.remote_field. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/1.9/#field-rel-changes

Answer (score 5):

I've also created an app you can just include in your project at http://github.com/sontek/django-tekextensions

Comment: Good answer but needs update. For example "ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX" is deprecated. django-tekextensions would be good if it had at last description... ;]

Comment: Your blog link is currently broken

Comment: It is always advised to quote from the page you are linking. In case the link is broken in the future, the answer still remains valid.

Answer (score 5):

Google pointed me to this page when searching how to get a "+" icon next to fields in a custom form with ForeignKey relationship (just like the admin site would do), so I thought I'd add.

For me, using `django-autocomplete-light` did the trick very well, using the "add another" functionality. See [this live demo](http://jpic.pythonanywhere.com/non_admin_add_another/widget/add/).

See [Django ModelChoiceField has no plus button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602563/django-modelchoicefield-has-no-plus-button/) as well.

Answer (score 1):

If in the **admin** you want to display **related objects** in **modals instead of old popup windows** I suggest you to try the `django-admin-interface`.

To install it follow these steps:

- `pip install django-admin-interface`
- Add `admin_interface`, `flat_responsive` and `colorfield` to `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` **before** `django.contrib.admin`
- `python manage.py migrate`
- `python manage.py collectstatic`

For more detailed info, see [django-admin-interface](https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/django-admin-interface) on GitHub.

Note: I am the author of this project