# No popup window when using "green plus" to add a record in my own app

Tags: javascript, django

I want to replicate the green plus from the admin site in my own app to add a record to a table. 
I have it mostly working (using mainly this: [Django admin - How can I add the green plus sign for Many-to-many Field in custom admin form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692822/django-admin-how-can-i-add-the-green-plus-sign-for-many-to-many-field-in-custo)), except that instead of a pop-up window, the add page loads in the same window and does not disappear when I click 'save'.

The following html is generated by my app, which appears OK (the onclick bit):

```
<a href="/admin/pricemanager/item/add/" class="add-another" id="add_id_form-0-item" onclick="return showAddAnotherPopup(this);">
```

But it appears that some javascript is missing at the top of the page. Am I forgetting to include something in my template?

I have found some related questions such as [Django Admin popup functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347582/django-admin-popup-functionality), but I don't understand the answers.

How can I make the pop-up work? (I would think that it should not be necessary to write lots of custom javascript - of which I know nothing - to make something work that already works in the admin app)

Comment: You would be missing `showAddAnotherPopup` function which is defined in _RelatedObjectLookups.js_ which shows a popup. Probably you would also need `dismissAddAnotherPopup`.

Comment: @Rohan: where do I find those and how/where do I insert/include them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include following in your template to load admin related JS.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/jsi18n/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/js/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>
```

This is with reference to answers for [Using Django time/date widgets in custom form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601/using-django-time-date-widgets-in-custom-form)